# Setting the jwt token in request header

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have built a OAuth2 client application using Spring security OAuth2 client library. Next, how to pass the jwt token as Authorization header while invoking a REST call to the Resource server. Is there any class which will inject the Auth code in the Request header seamlessly when building OAuth2 client application using Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

A very basic authentication flow is as follows:

1. Login endpoint is accessible without any security.
2. Upon successful login server sends HTTP response with "SET-COOKIE" header
   by specifying an auth cookie.
   [image: jwt cookie]
3. This cookie is stored by the browser for the domain that set it. Usually this is an HTTP cookie this means that we cannot access it via Javascript API.
4. For every subsequent request to the same domain, browser adds the cookie by itself.

Summary: All we need to do is to send the set-cookie header along with the token, browser will make sure it is sent for subsequent requests. In production make sure this cookie has secure and httpOnly attributes.

Image reference: [https://demey.io/jwt-tokens-for-distributed-authentica](https://demey.io/jwt-tokens-for-distributed-authentication/)tion/